# Query rows_examined greater than expected

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

So, I'm querying a product database, to find similar products:

```
select  productId,productName,productUrlId,productPrice
    from  tblProducts
    where  productCategoryId = 80
      and  MATCH(productName)
           AGAINST('Garmin eTrex' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

This query is taking ~6 seconds to complete and according to my slow query log, is examining ~820000 rows (table has ~4m rows).
What I dont understand is:

```
select productId,productName,productUrlId,productPrice
    from tblProducts 
    where productCategoryId = 80
```

returns 177 rows. So, why is my original query analyzing more than those 177 rows? shouldnt it first select the 177 rows, and *then* run the fulltext search on productName?

I have an index on productCategoryId and also a fulltext index on productName. Explain shows it using the productName index. If it matters, it's an innodb table.

EXPLAIN of first query:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type     | possible_keys                 | key         | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tblProducts | fulltext | productCategoryId,productName | productName | 0       |      |    1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

show create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblProducts` (
  `productId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productUrlId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `productMerchantId` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `productDescription` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `productPrice` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `productCategoryId` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `productImage` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `productAdded` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productUpdated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productId`),
  KEY `productImage_productUpdated` (`productImage`,`productUpdated`),
  KEY `productCategoryId` (`productCategoryId`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `productName` (`productName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4062618 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: What's the output of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`?

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Sorry, hopefully I've added the correct information now

Comment: How many rows "MATCH" _without_ the test for 80?

Comment: count(*) returns 834273 rows

Comment: even if I replace `productCategoryId = 80` with `productId in (14345,34243,177IDS)`, it still decides to analyze those 800k+ rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything off about the table creation. From the explain, mysql decides using the FULLTEXT `productName` key is better than using the `productCategoryId` key for some reason. It also looks like mysql doesn't support composite keys with FULLTEXT keys. I'd try running something like the following and comparing explains and speeds.

```sql
select productId,productName,productUrlId,productPrice from tblProducts 
where productCategoryId = 80 
and productName LIKE '%Garmin eTrex%'
```

You could also try using IGNORE_INDEX and USE_INDEX hints to see if the engine uses the correct index that way, or if using the other index actually helps.

Comment: While that may run faster _for these constants_, there is no good way to know when to do the query one way versus the other way.  The Optimizer has the same problem, so it blindly assumes it is better to start with FT.

Comment: I added in a USE/FORCE index(productCategoryId) , but it chose to ignore this.